# Regarding separate a single file into multiple files according to line separation

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, text-processing, files

Currently, I have a plain text file, A, such as

```
lowest priority
very high significance.
outstanding
very novel
```

In this file, every line contains a sentence. I want to separate this file into multiple files, and each file is composed of a single line of the original file, A. For instance, with respect to the example file A, I want to generate four files:

- A1, which has single line, `lowest priority`
- A2, which has single line, `very high significance`
- A3, which has single line, `outstanding`
- A4, which has single line, `very novel`.

How to do that under linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do it using `split` command. E.g.:

```
split -l1 -d -a 3 A A
```

Check `man split` for details.

Answer (score 3):

Also, awk is pretty straightforward:

```
awk '{filename = FILENAME NR; print > filename; close(filename)}' A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=1; while IFS= read -r line; do printf %s\\n "$line" > A$n; n=$((n+1)); done <A
```